# SPListItem : CopyFieldMask , Value does not fall within the expected range C#

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, sharepoint-addin, splistitem

When I am trying to update a list item, I get an error
CopyFieldMask , Value does not fall within the expected range
My code is as follows:

```
    SPQuery  oquery=new SPQuery();
    oquery.Query= "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /> <Value Type='Counter'>"+strid+"</Value></Eq></Where>";
oquery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Status' />";
    SPListItemCollection collistitems= listPartner.GetItems(oquery);
    SPListItem newItem=collistitems[0];//i get error here saying CopyField mask throws Argument exception and value doesn't not fall within the expected range
    newItem["Status"]="Supplied";
    newItem.Update();//Exceptions occurs
```

I tried by changing the value in resource throttling from 12 to 15 although I am not using any Lookups
I also tried using ViewFields in my CAML query
and the Internal name of Status Column is same.

Please assist me with this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you try hard coding the value of strid and trying the same ? check if u still get the error? 
   i.e  replace "+strid+" by an id value from the list
2. ensure the value passes is an integer

Comment: hi Polika,
yes It is an integer value and also tried by hardcoding the value of strID, still no success.